# Video timecode using RTMP / AVCONV (ffmpeg) / NGINX

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, avconv

to insert a time code in a video I use

```
avconv -y -i in.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/DroidSans.ttf: fontsize=22: timecode='00\:00\:00\:00': r=25: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5" -an -y out.mp4
```

when reading the video

```
ffplay out.mp4
```

everything is ok but when using a pipe to feed the rtmp server and then reading the stream with ffplay the time code won't display. Is it due to the flv conversion ?

for example streaming from a raspberry pi camera

```
/opt/vc/bin/raspivid -n -hf -vf -fl -mm matrix -w 800 -h 600 -fps 25 -g 80 -t 0 -b 6000000 -o - | avconv -re -i - -nostats -c copy -vf "drawtext= ..... -f flv rtmp://myserver/cam/live
```

doesn't output the timecode.

Comment: Pretty sure your timecode is getting put into the MP4 container... Can rtmp stream mp4s ... I haven't followed flash video too closely

Comment: no it doesn't unfortunately . When trying to ouput a mp4 format  it raises [mp4 @ 0x1fe2c20] muxer does not support non seekable output

Comment: Remove the `-c copy` If you're using a filter, you can't copy the video. You can then add a `-c:a copy` to copy the audio over.